# Solving a mixed radical and quadratic equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, roots, radicals

> Solve for $x \in \mathbb{R}$
>
> $$4x^2(x+2) +3(2x^2-4x-3)\sqrt{4x+3} +6x = 0$$

I tried taking square by isolating the radical, but the resultant equation couldn't be solved.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you are expected to make an educated guess here by checking values of $x$ which cause $4x+3$ to be a perfect square. But then $x$ cannot be an integer since all odd squares are of the form $4n+1$.  So $\frac{3}{2}$ would be a good first guess since $4\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)+3=9$. Checking this value verifies that it is a solution. To see if there are other real solutions would require eliminating the radical and applying perhaps Descartes Rule of signs and other tests.

Comment: Confession: I actually tried $\frac{1}{4}$ first but it was not a solution. You would also check $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $X=4x+3$. Then,
$$3(2x^2-X)\sqrt{X}=-2x(2x^2+X)$$
Squaring the both sides gives
$$9(2x^2-X)^2X=4x^2(2x^2+X)^2,$$
i.e.
$$4x^4X-4x^2X^2+9X^3-16x^6+16x^4X-36x^2X^2=0$$
$$X(4x^4-4x^2X+9X^2)-4x^2(4x^4-4x^2X+9X^2)=0$$
$$(X-4x^2)(4x^4-4x^2X+9X^2)=0$$
since $9X^2=X^2+8X^2$
$$(X-4x^2)(4x^4-4x^2X+X^2+8X^2)=0$$
to have
$$(X-4x^2)((2x^2-X)^2+8X^2)=0$$
finally,
$$(-4x^2+4x+3)((2 x^2-4 x-3)^2+8 (4 x+3)^2)=0$$
and so
$$x=\frac 32,-\frac 12.$$
The former is sufficient while the latter isn't. So, $\color{red}{x=\frac 32}$ is the only solution.

Comment: Excellent! (+1)

Comment: Hello Sir. Can you also help me with [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1770880/solve-the-equation-for-x-in-mathbbr) ?